# Overriding an entry in paths-common.conf with paths-common.local in fail2ban?

Tags: configuration, fail2ban

OS is CentOS 6.9, with `fail2ban-0.9.6-1.el6.1.noarch`

According to the [fail2ban manual](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Configuration):

> Every .conf file can be overridden with a file named .local. The .conf file is read first, then .local, with later settings overriding earlier ones. Thus, a .local file doesn't have to include everything in the corresponding .conf file, only those settings that you wish to override.
>
> Modifications should take place in the .local and not in the .conf. This avoids merging problem when upgrading. These files are well documented and detailed information should be available there.

However, this does not seem to apply to the `paths-*.conf` files.  I tried creating `paths-common.local` to override:

```
dovecot_log = /var/log/dovecot.log
```

but this was ignored.  I found I had to modify `paths-common.conf` to get fail2ban to look at the right log file.

Did I misunderstand, or is the documentation just a bit too eager with "*Every* `.conf` file..." (or maybe it's a bug I should file in the tracker?)

Comment: What operating system and fail2ban version are you using?

Comment: Have you read this: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/820#issuecomment-57445680 to check which files are read and if the file is probably called `files-overrides.local`?

Comment: @sebix OS and version added to the post

Comment: As to the link, that seems to be it, I'm not where I can test it right now but will try it tomorrow.  Based on the lack of hits in an explicit search for `file2ban files-overrides` (except for the link you provided) it appears that `files-overrides.conf` isn't documented.

Answer (score 1):

In the `fail2ban` current version of [`paths-common.conf`](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/config/paths-common.conf) there is a section at the top for `includes`:

```
[INCLUDES]

after  = paths-overrides.local
```

To override `paths-common.conf` create `paths-overrides.local` in the `fail2ban` directory & add a default **section header** to the top of it:

```
[DEFAULT]

dovecot_log = /path/to/mail.log
```